# How to assign variadic template arguments to std::array

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

I have an `std::array` and I have a variadic template function with the number of parameters that matches the size of the array. I need to assign the arguments to the elements of the array. In other words, in the code below I wish `a` to get values `{1, 2, 3}` and `b` to get values `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

```
std::array<int, 3> a;
std::array<int, 5> b;

assign_values(a, 1, 2, 3);
assign_values(b, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

The question is how to implement the `assign_values` variadic template function.

I'm limited with the C++14 version.

**Update:**
The arguments can be of different types: `assign_values(b, 1, 2u, 3., '4', 5l);`

Comment: I'm confused: why is this tagged C++11 if you can use C++14?

Comment: @Chipster that just means that I can use C++11 but cannot use C++17. There is nothing in my question specific to C++14.

Comment: Got you. My thing though is since most C++ versions are backwards compatible, wouldn't it be best to put the most recent version you could use as a tag? That's just my thought process. You certainly don't have to tag it that way, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sth like this:

```
template<class T, size_t N, class ... Values>
void assign_values(std::array<T,N>& arr, Values... vals) {
    static_assert(N == sizeof...(vals));
    int j = 0;
    for (auto i : std::initializer_list< std::common_type_t<Values...> >{vals...})
        arr[j++] = i;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ZIeQKf)

Comment: Or even `void assign_values(std::array<int,N>& arr, Values... vals) { arr = {vals...}; }

Comment: @Kit. yep, also your solution is nicer and simpler :)

Comment: @rafix07 This solution is not generic. You provide generic types `Values` but iterate just integers: `for (int i : {vals...})`

Comment: @rafix07 One more complication: in your snippet all `Values` are integers (at least they are of the same type). What if we use different types (even those that doesn't loose precision)? `assign_values(b, 1, 2u, 3., '4');`

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov initializer list must have all values with one type. So you can use `common_type_t` to deduce it. Then you can mix float, integers, chars in input parameter pack.

Comment: @rafix07, @Kit. This solution works, however having a loop in template is not the best choice. I've tried the `arr = {vals...};` and this works even without common type deduction. Now I'm confused: why don't I need to deduce in this case?

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov Kit's solutions based on [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm limited with the C++14 version

The good old trick of the unused array initialization (pre C++17 surrogate of template folding) should works (also C++11)

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename ... Values>
void assign_values (std::array<T,N> & arr, Values... vals)
 {
    static_assert(N == sizeof...(vals));

    using unused = int[];

    int j = 0;

    (void)unused { 0, (arr[j++] = vals, 0)... };
 }
```